# Inhomogeneous 2D steady state heat equation with uniform heat source

Tags: partial-differential-equations

A square slab of width $L$ and with uniform heat-input $Q$ is insulated perfectly at top and bottom and found at steady state.

Fourier's equation for this case:

$$k(u_{xx}+u_{yy})+Q=0$$
where $k$ is the thermal diffusivity.

The boundary conditions are:

$$u(0,y)=u(L,y)=u(x,0)=u(x,L)=0$$

For the $\text{1D}$ case:

$$ku''(x)+Q=0$$

BC: $u(0)=u(L)=0$

Which solves simply to:

$$u(x)=-\frac{Q}{2k}x^2+\frac{QL}{2k}x=\frac{Q}{2k}(Lx-x^2)$$

---

But for the $\text{2D}$ case things are harder.

Separation of variables doesn't work here because of the $Q$ term.

And solving the homogeneous case first only yields:

$$u(x,y)=0$$

Someone pointing me in a workable condition would be much appreciated.

---

**Suggested by @jon:**

Substitution $u \to w$:

$$u(x,y)=w(x,y)-\frac{Q}{4k}(x^2+y^2)$$

So that:

$$k\Big(w_{xx}-\frac{Q}{2k}+w_{yy}-\frac{Q}{2k}\Big)+Q=0$$

$$kw_{xx}-\frac{Q}{2}+kw_{yy}-\frac{Q}{2}+Q=0$$

$$\Rightarrow w_{xx}+w_{yy}=0$$

But the boundary conditions in $w$ aren't homogeneous...

---

The new boundary conditions for $w(x,y)$ become:

$w(0,y)=\frac{Q}{4k}y^2$

$w(L,y)=\frac{Q}{4k}y^2$

$w(x,0)=\frac{Q}{4k}x^2$

$w(x,L)=\frac{Q}{4k}x^2$

According to [Paul's online notes][1] this can be solved by starting from:

$$w(x,y)=w_1(x,y)+w_2(x,y)+w_3(x,y)+w_4(x,y)$$

> To completely solve Laplace’s equation we’re in fact going to have to
> solve it four times. Each time we solve it only one of the four
> boundary conditions can be nonhomogeneous while the remaining three
> will be homogeneous.

In essence this is applying the Superposition Principle 'in reverse'.

For example for $w_4(x,y)$ we'd have:

$$w_{4,xx}+w_{4,yy}=0$$

$w_4(0,y)=\frac{Q}{4k}y^2$

$w_4(L,y)=0$

$w_4(x,0)=0$

$w_4(x,L)=0$

Ansatz: $w_4=X(x)Y(y)$

Separation of variables:

$$\frac{Y''}{Y}=-\frac{X''}{X}=-m^2$$

Or:

$$Y''+m^2Y=0 \Rightarrow Y(y)=A\sin my+B\cos my$$
$$X''-m^2X=0 \Rightarrow X(x)=C\cosh mx+D\sinh mx$$

BC:

$Y(0)=Y(L)=0 \Rightarrow B=0$

and:

$\sin mL=0 \Rightarrow mL=\pi n \Rightarrow m=\frac{\pi n}{L} \text{ for } n=1,2,3...$

$$Y(y)=\sin\Big(\frac{\pi n y}{L}\Big)$$

Rewrite $X(x)=C\cosh\Big(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\Big) +D\sinh \Big(\frac{\pi n x}{L}\Big)$

to: $X(x)=C\cosh\Big(\frac{\pi n (x-L)}{L}\Big) +D\sinh \Big(\frac{\pi n (x-L)}{L}\Big)$

$X(L)=0 \Rightarrow X(x)=D\sinh \Big(\frac{\pi n (x-L)}{L}\Big)$

$$w_{4,n}=G_n\sinh \Big(\frac{\pi n (x-L)}{L}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{\pi n y}{L}\Big)\text{ for }n=1,2,3...$$

Using $w_4(0,y)=\frac{Q}{4k}y^2$ and the Fourier sine series, the amplitudes $G_n$ can be determined.

The above process is repeated another $3$ times.

[1] https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/LaplacesEqn.aspx

Comment: Change to $u=w-\frac{Q}{2k}(x^2+y^2)$ than solve for $w$.

Comment: Did you mean $u(x,y)=w(x,y)-\frac{Q}{4k}(x^2+y^2)$? That gets rid of the 'offending' $Q$.

Comment: Yes, then the solution is straightforwardly obtained.

Comment: It's a **great trick** but it does bugger up these nice homogeneous BCs?